# can't call two methods onSubmit react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Login component that should be reusable in two cases: in the first case, the parent modal does not close after login; in the second case it does close after login.

So i though I would write two methods and call both in one method used with `onSubmit`. But I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: login is not defined

Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

export default class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.closeModalAfterLogin = this.closeModalAfterLogin.bind(this);
  }

  handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    login();
    closeModalAfterLogin();
  }

  login() {
    let email = this.refs.email.value.trim();
    let password = this.refs.password.value.trim();
    Meteor.loginWithPassword({email}, password, err =>{
      console.log('Login Callback', err);
    })
  }

  closeModalAfterLogin() {
    if (this.props.closeAfterLogin) {
      this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
      console.log('closing modal');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="email" ref="email" className="form-control" id="login-form-input-email" placeholder="email"/>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="password" ref="password" className="form-control" id="login-form-input-password" placeholder="mot de passe"/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Connexion</button>
        </form>
        <p>Pas encore de compte ? <a onClick={this.props.toggleHasAnAccount}>Inscrivez-vous</a></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be this.login()

Comment: use `this.functionName()` to call any class method, so use `this.login(); this.closeModalAfterLogin();`

Answer (score 1):

I have the changes in the way you call the login and handle the login callback from your login function basically calling `this.closeModalAfterLogin()` in your login call back.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

export default class LoginForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
        modalIsOpen: false
      }
  }
  handleLogin = () => {
    let email = this.refs.email.value.trim();
    let password = this.refs.password.value.trim();
    Meteor.loginWithPassword({email}, password, err => {
      if(err){
        console.log('Login Error callback', err);
      }else{
          console.log('Login Success');
          this.closeModalAfterLogin();
      }
    })
  }

  closeModalAfterLogin = () => {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: false });
    console.log('closing modal');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="email" ref="email" className="form-control" id="login-form-input-email" placeholder="email"/>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="password" ref="password" className="form-control" id="login-form-input-password" placeholder="mot de passe"/>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Connexion</button>
        </form>
        <p>Pas encore de compte ? <a onClick={this.props.toggleHasAnAccount}>Inscrivez-vous</a></p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Anshul Bansal ! I did the same thing for `closeModalAfterlogin()`. However, in the case my modal should close, it actually does not. why ? the function seems to run though.

Comment: It didn't work because you have a condition  `if (this.props.closeAfterLogin) { ` which may be false in your case.

Comment: i debbuged it and it gives `true`

Answer (score 1):

Change the functions calls as

```
handleLogin(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.login();
    this.closeModalAfterLogin();
  }
```